# How to remove an element in jsonb integer array in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

On Postgres, in a table called "photo" I have a jsonb column called "id_us" containing a json integer array, simply like this one **[1,2,3,4]**
I would like to find the query to remove the element 3 for example.
The closer I could get is this

```
SELECT jsonb_set(id_us, ''
               , (SELECT jsonb_agg(val)
                  FROM   jsonb_array_elements(p.id_us) x(val)
                  WHERE  val <> jsonb '3')
                 ) AS id_us
FROM   photo p;
```

Any idea how to solve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery containing `JSONB_AGG()` function while filtering out the index value `3`(*by starting indexing from 1*) such as

```
WITH p AS
(
 SELECT JSONB_AGG(j) AS js 
   FROM photo 
  CROSS JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(id_us) 
   WITH ORDINALITY arr(j,idx)
  WHERE idx != 3
)
UPDATE photo
   SET id_us = js
  FROM p
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=90e48779a5c621f10d4b6c5eb4d92a69)</kbd>

**Edit :** If you need to remove the value but not index as mentioned in the comment, just use the variable `j` casted as numeric

```
WITH p AS
(
 SELECT JSONB_AGG(j) AS js 
   FROM photo 
  CROSS JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(id_us) 
   WITH ORDINALITY arr(j,idx)
  WHERE j::INT != 18
)
UPDATE photo
   SET id_us = js
  FROM p
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=185d1b8dfd43d4bbfaf72f18ddad43f0)</kbd>

P.S: using `JSONB_SET()`, the comma-seperated place for the removed element along with quotes will still remain in such a way that in the following

```
WITH p AS
(
 SELECT ('{'||idx-1||'}')::TEXT[] AS idx 
   FROM photo 
  CROSS JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(id_us) 
   WITH ORDINALITY arr(j,idx)
  WHERE j::INT = 18
)
UPDATE photo
   SET id_us = JSONB_SET(id_us,idx,'""')
  FROM p; 

SELECT * FROM photo;

id_us
-----------------
[127, 52, "", 44]
```

Comment: Thank you but it was maybe not clear in my question, I would like to remove the VALUE "3", not the element at the index 3. Another example, I want to remove the value 18 in all rows of the table having a JSON like this for example  [127, 52, 18, 44]. Can you help me on this?

Comment: Hi @Philiz , you're welcome. I've just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've run across a similar issue, and it stems from the `-` operator. This operator is overloaded to accept either text or integer, but acts differently for each type. Using text will remove by value, and using an integer will remove by index. But what if your value IS an integer? Well then you're shit outta luck...

If possible, you can try changing your jsonb integer array to a jsonb string array (of integers), and then  the `-` operator should work smoothly.

e.g.

```
'{1,2,3}' - 2 = '{1,2}'  -- removes index 2
'{1,2,3}' - '2' = '{1,2,3}' -- removes values == '2' (but '2' != 2)
'{"1","2","3"}' - 2 = '{"1","2"}' -- removes index 2
'{"1","2","3"}' - '2' = '{"1","3"}' -- removes values == '2'
```

**If you run into a situation where you need to remove elements from an Integer array of type jsonb, you can solve it this way (albeit with some complexity)**

```
UPDATE table
SET integer_array_coloum = 
(
    SELECT jsonb_agg(value::int) 
    FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(integer_array_coloum) 
    WHERE value::int <> 2
)
WHERE tag_ids @> '2';
```